# node js send token through the header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

i try to send token use  header, (login form to index page use the header)

```
 router.post('/login',async(req,res)=>{
    const {error} = logvali(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    //check if the email exist
    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if(!user) return res.status(400).send('Email is Wrong');
    //password  is correct
    const vapass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password , user.password);
    if(!vapass) return res.status(400).send('Password is Wrong');

    const token =jwt.sign({_id: user._id},process.env.TOK);
    res.header('authtok',token).redirect('/index');

});
```

my index file is

```
app.get('/index',verift, function(req, res, next) {
res.render('index');
});
```

the page redirect index page ,but the token not send the index page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass headers while doing res.redirect in express js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997413/how-to-pass-headers-while-doing-res-redirect-in-express-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you expect that the `authtok` header will be set by the browser when a request to `/index` page is made.
Headers are not cookies (tho cookies are passed in a header). If you set a header in a response, the browser will receive that header but it will NOT be inserted in any of the subsequent queries made by the browser.
In this case you have to explicitly read, store and set `authtok` header in a subsequent request.