# How to pass the value of a button ID into a GET request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a Node.js application which used a database that consists of many students and their current marks. I am able to view this in a table by first getting the data from MongoDB and sending it to the .ejs file.

**index.js**

```
router.get("/dashboard", function (req, res) {
  markModel.find({}, function (err, allDetails) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("marks", { details: allDetails});
    }
  });
});
```

**marks.ejs**

```
<% if(details!=null) { %>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Student</th>
    <th>Mark</th>
</tr>
<% details.forEach(function(item){ %>
<tr>
    <td><%= item.name%></td>
    <td><%= item.mark%></td>
</tr>
<% }) %>
</table>
```

What I want to do is create an **Update** button in every row that will take me to a separate page where I can update a student's mark. I thought of adding a button where I can use the `_id` to identify the record but I'm not sure how to pass this value into a `GET` request to the page where I can update the marks separately.

```
<td><a href="/update" class="btn btn-secondary" id = <%= item._id%> >Update</a></td>
```

Another approach I had was using a form.

```
<form method="post" action="/marks">
     <input type="submit" id="<%= item._id%>" name="<%= item._id%>" value="Update">
</form>
```

But I got stuck on how to how to pass the value of `_id` while redirecting to `/update`.

```
router.post("/dashboard", function (req, res) {
   res.redirect("/update")
});
```

This is what I have so far. I'm not sure what to give for the reqID so I have left it blank.

```
router.get("/update", (req, res) =>
  res.render("update", {
    reqID: 
  })
);
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I can add and how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add an hidden input to the form. By doing so, you can easily provide any data you want to the request.

```
<form method="post" action="/update">
     <input type="number" name="id_name" value="<%= item._id =>" hidden>
     <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Assuming that you are using a [bodyParser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html), you will be able to reach the data by doing the following:

```
router.get("/update", (req, res) =>
  res.render("update", {
    reqID: req.body.id_name
  })
);
```

Comment: Hi. The form here is sending a post request directly to `/update`. I want to it to post to `/dashboard`.  I will be using other forms in `/update` so will that POST request cause a problem too?

Comment: @vnk Maybe I did not fully understand your question :) If you want to show the page for updating this specific resource, just change the form method to GET. However, if you would to actually update the data, keep it as a POST request.

Comment: Okay. I'll try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

make a link like that : ?id=VALUEOFTHEID

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you can pass the values in redirect.

As the [document](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) suggests, you can pass the value as a param or you can pass it in query or in header.

To pass it in query or Cookie, follow this [solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context)
To pass it in header, follow this [solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997413/how-to-pass-headers-while-doing-res-redirect-in-express-js)